Equivalence of definitions of residual nilpotence of groups
Let $G$ be a group. Then we define $G_n$ recursively for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ as
$$G_n = \begin{cases}G & \text{if }n= 0,\\ [G_{n-1},G] & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
Where $[H,K] = \lbrace [h,k]\mid h\in H, k\in K\rbrace = \lbrace hkh^{-1}k^{-1}\mid h\in H, k\in K\rbrace$.
Lemma: If $H,K\triangleleft G$, then $[H,K]\triangleleft G$.
Proof: Indeed, if $g,h,k$ are elements of $G$, $H$, and $K$, respectively, then
$$\begin{align*}
g[h,k]g^{-1} &= ghkh^{-1}k^{-1}g^{-1} \\
&= gh(g^{-1}g)k(g^{-1}g)h^{-1}(g^{-1}g)k^{-1}g^{-1} \\
&= (ghg^{-1})(gkg^{-1})(gh^{-1}g^{-1})(gk^{-1}g^{-1}) \\
&= (ghg^{-1})(gkg^{-1})(ghg^{-1})^{-1}(gkg^{-1})^{-1} \\
&= [ghg^{-1},gkg^{-1}].
\end{align*}$$
But $H\triangleleft G$, so $ghg^{-1}\in H$. Similarly, $gkg^{-1}\in K$. This means that $g[h,k]g^{-1}\in [H,K]$, as desired.
$\square$
This clearly implies that $G_n\triangleleft G$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Since $G_{n+1}\subseteq G_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then we have
$$G = G_0\triangleright G_1 \triangleright \ldots \triangleright G_n \triangleright \ldots$$
Definition: The group $G$ is nilpotent if $G_n = \lbrace e\rbrace$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

From this notation and definition, we can define residually nilpotent groups. I have encountered the following definitions in the literature:
Definition 1: The group $G$ is residually nilpotent if for all nontrivial element $g\in G$ there is a nilpotent group $H$ and a group homomorphism $\varphi:G\to H$ that sends $g$ to a nontrivial element.
Definition 2: The group $G$ is residually nilpotent if for all nontrivial element $g\in G$ there is a normal subgroup $N\triangleleft G$ not containing $g$, such that $G/N$ is nilpotent.
Definition 3: The group $G$ is residually nilpotent if
$$\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty G_n = \lbrace e \rbrace.$$

I want to prove that these definitions are equivalent. Here is my (partial) attempt:
$3\implies 2$: If the intersection of the $G_n$ is trivial, then, given some nontrivial $g\in G$, we have some $k$ for which $g\notin G_k$. By our lemma, $G_k\triangleleft G$. All left to prove is that the quotient group $H = G/G_k$ is nilpotent. Indeed, for $1\leq n \leq k$ we have
$$H_n = [H_{n-1},H] \stackrel{*}{\cong} \left[\frac{G_{n-1}}{G_k},\frac{G}{G_k}\right] \stackrel{*}{\cong} \frac{[G_{n-1},G]}{G_k} = \frac{G_n}{G_k},$$
but then $H_k = \lbrace e\rbrace$.
(*) Is this correct?
$2\implies 1$: This is obvious by taking $H = G/N$.
$1\implies 3$: Here is where I'm stumped.

Lemma. Let $f\colon G\to K$ be a surjective group homomorphism. Then $f(G_n) = K_n$.
This follows from the fact that the $n$th term of the lower central series is a verbal subgroup, but here is an explicit proof:
Proof. We proceed by induction on $n$. By assumption, $K_0 = K = f(G)=f(G_0)$.
Assume $f(G_n)=K_n$. Let $[x,k]$ be a generator of $K_{n+1}$, where $x\in K_n$ and $k\in K$. Since $f(G_n)=K_n$, there exists $y\in G_n$ such that $f(y)=x$; and since $f$ is surjective, there exists $g\in G$ such that $f(g) = k$. Then $f([y,g]) = [f(y),f(g)] = [x,k]$; since $[y,g]\in [G_n,G]=G_{n+1}$, we conclude that $f(G_{n+1})$ contains all generators of $K_{n+1}$. Therefore, $K_{n+1}\subseteq f(G_{n+1})$. Conversely, if $x\in G_n$ and $g\in G$, then $f([x,g]) = [f(x),f(g)]\in [K_n,K]=K_{n+1}$, so $f(G_{n+1})\subseteq K_{n+1}$, proving equality. $\Box$
Corollary. Let $G$ be a group. If $k\leq n$, then $(G/G_n)_k = G_k/G_n$.
Proof. Let $\pi\colon G\to G/G_n$ be the canonical projection. Then $\pi(G_k) = (G/G_n)_k$, and since $G_n\leq G_k$, we have $\pi(G_k) = G_k/G_n$. $\Box$
So your (*) is correct, but I would say it is not immediately obvious and needs justification.
Corollary. Let $G$ be a group. For all $n\geq 0$, $G/G_n$ is nilpotent.
Proof. We have $(G/G_n)_n = G_n/G_n$, which is trivial. $\Box$
This gives you the proof of $1\implies 3$: let $g\in G$, $g\neq e$, and let $H$ be a nilpotent group with $f\colon G\to H$ a morphism such that $f(g)\neq e$. We can replace $H$ with $f(G)$, which is also nilpotent (subgroup of nilpotent group is nilpotent), so we may assume that $f$ is surjective.
In particular, there exists $k$ such that $H_k=\{e\}$, and therefore  $f(G_k) = H_k =\{e\}$. Thus, we have $G_k\subseteq \ker(f)$. Since $g\notin \ker(f)$, then $g\notin G_k$, so $g\notin \bigcap_{k=0}^{\infty}G_k$, as desired.

I used that lemma earlier in my document. I had no idea I could also use it for this purpose! Thank you!
